# What's the best way to hash a string vector not very long (urls)?

Tags: c++, hash

I am now dealing with url classification. I partition url with "/?", etc, generating a bunch of parts. In the process, I need to hash the first part to the kth part, say, k=2, then for "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", the key is a string vector "stackoverflow.com questions". Currently, the hash is like Hash. But it consumes a lot of memory. I wonder whether MD5 can help or are there other alternatives. In effect, I do not need to recover the key exactly, as long as differentiating different keys.
Thanks!

Comment: `Currently, the hash is like Hash.` - I have no idea what you mean by that. And what is consuming a lot of memory, storing hash-codes or computing them?

Comment: Here are some more things to consider if you are trying to optimize around lookup/hashing.  Where does your application spend most of its time/memory - generating hashes, or looking them up?  When your list approaches infinity (or your bucket size), you will have some form of collisions.  Can your application handle this?  If it can't, then you may encounter this as a bug at some point, and it may be hard to debug.  If it can, and it happens often, then you may want to look into hashing algorithms that give good distribution for your data.

Answer (score 1):

> It consumes a lot of memory

If your code already works, you may want to consider leaving it as-is.  If you don't have a target, you won't know when you're done.  Are you sure "a lot" is synonymous with "too much" in your case?

If you decide you really need to change your working code, you should consider the large variety of the options you have available, rather than taking someone's word for a specific algorithm:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions
- http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions

etc

Not sure about memory implications, and it certainly would change your perf profile, but you could also look into using Tries:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is a nice hash code for stuff where security is not an issue. It's fast and reasonably long (128 bits is enough for most applications). Also the distribution is very good.

[Adler32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) would be a possible alternative. It's very easy to implement, just a few lines of code. It's even faster then MD5. And it's long enough/good enough for many applications (though for many it is not).
(I know Adler32 is strictly not a hash-code, but it will still do fine for many applications)

However, if storing the hash-code is consuming a lot of memory, you can always truncate the hash-code, or use XOR to "shrink" it. E.g.

```
uint8_t md5[16];
GetMD5(md5, ...);

// use XOR to shrink the MD5 to 32 bits
for (size_t i = 4; i < 16; i++)
    md5[i % 4] ^= md5[i];

// assemble the parts into one uint32_t
uint32_t const hash = md5[0] + (md5[1] << 8) + (md5[2] << 16) + (md5[3] << 24);
```

Personally I think MD5 would be overkill though. Have a look at [Adler32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32), I think it will do.

---

**EDIT**

I have to correct myself: Adler23 is a rather poor choice for short strings (less then a few thousand bytes). I had completely forgotten about that. But there is always the obvious: CRC32. Not as fast as Adler23 (about the same speed as MD5), but still acceptably easy to implement, and there are also a ton of existing implementations with all kinds of licenses out there.

Comment: +1.  Adler32 looks like a decent option.  It seems to fit what I assume his needs are (low memory consumption while executing the hashing function, and outputting a 32 bit int).  There are tons of other options out there that fit the same profile, but it looks very simple to implement and debug, and might work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to find out if two URL's are the same have you considered storing a binary version of the IP address of the server? If two server names resolve to the same address is that incorrect or an advantage for your application?

Comment: I can't pretend to know his needs, but this certainly wouldn't work in the case where he was trying to separately store two urls that are serviced by the same server.

Comment: There is one problem though: URL:IP ist not a N:1 mapping, it's N:N.